# Layout and export URLs

Tags: macros, environments, urls, write

I use LaTeX for technical documentation of test-scenarios of a software system. The idea is as follows:

- I write a test scenario in LaTeX. In this test-scenario, I use pieces of data that are configurable and which are defined in a LaTeX environment.
- Upon compilation of the LaTeX document I want a nice PDF with the test descriptions, but also a .properties file, which simply lists all data items as a key value pair and which is directly used by the test-suite. This way, updating the test documentation will automatically update the executable tests.

I have create an environment to achieve this as follows:

```
\edef\althashchar{\string#\space}%
\newcounter{datasnippets}
\newcommand{\datasnippet}[4]{%
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\unexpanded{#1=#4}}
  \refstepcounter{datasnippets}\label{data:#1}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1lc\endcsname{\MakeLowercase{#2}}%    
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Description\endcsname{#3}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Value\endcsname{\code{#4}}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Full\endcsname{#3 (value: \code{#4})}%
  \thedatasnippets. & #2 & \code{#4} & #3 \\
    \addlinespace
}
\newenvironment{datasnippets}
 {
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=scenarios.properties
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\althashchar This is a generated file, *DO NOT EDIT* directly.}
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\althashchar Instead, update the data snippets inside the data.tex file of the scenarios documentation and regenerate.}

    \par
        \small
        \begin{longtable}{
            p{0.4cm}
            p{4cm}
            p{3cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-0.4cm-4cm-3cm\relax}
        }
        \toprule
        & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Description} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
 }
 {%
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile
 }
```

Then, I simply do the following:

```
\begin{datasnippets}
    \datasnippet{carName}{Car name}{The name (full brand and type) of the car used in the crash-test}{Bugatti Veyron}
\end{datasnippets}
```

Now, I can simply refer to \carName , \carNameValue , \carNameDescription depending on what I want to use in my document and I get a nice export of the variable and the value in my .properties file at the end.

The problem is that I can't get it to work properly with things such as URLs. Those need to be escaped for LaTeX, but they should *NOT* be escaped when writing out to the file.

How do I create a datasnippet where the value is a URL? So ideally, I just want to do something like:

```
\begin{datasnippets}
    \datasnippet{shop}{Online store}{The online store used for the order.}{http://www.mycoolstore.com/}
\end{datasnippets}
```

It should be in the .properties file as follows:

```
shop=http://www.mycoolstore.com/
```

**EDIT:**

My question is actually more general than just URLs, it is about everything that LaTeX requires escaping for. For example, if I have a variable of the form A_B, I can not simply type that in my \datasnippet command as I need to escape the _, but the output to the properties file also exports those escape characters. So If I have following code:

```
\begin{datasnippets}
    \datasnippet{someCode}{A secret code}{Just some difficult to typeset thing.}{A\_B14879/C\_D}
\end{datasnippets}
```

That will be exported as:

```
someCode=A\_B14879/C\_D
```

But I would like to see:

```
someCode=A_B14879/C_D
```

Here is a full working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\date{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newwrite\tempfile


\edef\althashchar{\string#\space}%
\newcounter{datasnippets}
\newcommand{\datasnippet}[4]{%
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\unexpanded{#1=#4}}
  \refstepcounter{datasnippets}\label{data:#1}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1lc\endcsname{\MakeLowercase{#2}}%    
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Description\endcsname{#3}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Value\endcsname{\code{#4}}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Full\endcsname{#3 (waarde: \code{#4})}%
  \thedatasnippets. & #2 & \code{#4} & #3 \\
    \addlinespace
}
\newenvironment{datasnippets}
 {
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=scenarios.properties
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\althashchar This is a generated file, *DO NOT EDIT* directly.}
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\althashchar Instead, update the data snippets inside the data.tex file of the scenarios documentation and regenerate.}

    \par
        \small
        \begin{longtable}{
            p{0.4cm}
            p{4cm}
            p{3cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-0.4cm-4cm-3cm\relax}
        }
        \toprule
        & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Description} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
 }
 {%
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile
 }


\begin{document}

\section{Data Overview}
\begin{datasnippets}
% Formaat: naam (dit wordt in het document gebruikt om het commando te gebruiken), korte beschrijving (KORT!), lange beschrijving (duidelijk!), waarde (enkel de waarde, liefst in \code{} wrap)
\datasnippet{someVariable}{Variable}{Just an example}{ThisWorks}
\datasnippet{aProblem}{Problem Variable}{An illustration of a value that layouts fine, but is exported incorrectly.}{A\_B01}
\end{datasnippets}

\section{Data Usage}

As you can see, I can now simply refer to \someVariableValue\ and its full description: \someVariableFull . A side effect is that upon compiling, a properties file is generated which can be used during testing.

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: You could use the `\texttt{\detokenize{...}}` in your TeX file. Or you might use `\url{}` provided by `hyperref`.

Comment: It wasn't clear from my original question, but it's not just about URLs, but any other escapable sequence of characters. Maybe the detokenize works, but I do not really see where I should add it then?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete compilable example (beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`)

Comment: I have added a full compilable example. Thanks for your time. The essence is that I can simply use the defined commands in my document, and that they are exported correctly in the output file. I prefer a more complex definition of my environment over a more complex escaping/usage as non-latex people will be defining test scenarios and datasnippets as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does work for the examples you provided so far:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\def\myurl{http://www.my_coolstore.com/}% no escaped underscores
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=scenarios.properties

\begin{document}
\texttt{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\myurl}}% this prints the url in the pdf
\immediate\write\tempfile{\myurl}% this puts the url in your file
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Working example of your MWE with adaptions to your `\code`. You mustn't escape the underscores (no `\_`) with the new `\code`. Then it works fine for me.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\date{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}}
\newwrite\tempfile


\edef\althashchar{\string#\space}%
\newcounter{datasnippets}
\newcommand{\datasnippet}[4]{%
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\unexpanded{#1=#4}}
  \refstepcounter{datasnippets}\label{data:#1}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1lc\endcsname{\MakeLowercase{#2}}%    
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Description\endcsname{#3}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Value\endcsname{\code{#4}}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Full\endcsname{#3 (waarde: \code{#4})}%
  \thedatasnippets. & #2 & \code{#4} & #3 \\
    \addlinespace
}
\newenvironment{datasnippets}
 {
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=scenarios.properties
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\althashchar This is a generated file, *DO NOT EDIT* directly.}
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\althashchar Instead, update the data snippets inside the data.tex file of the scenarios documentation and regenerate.}

    \par
        \small
        \begin{longtable}{
            p{0.4cm}
            p{4cm}
            p{3cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-0.4cm-4cm-3cm\relax}
        }
        \toprule
        & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Description} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
 }
 {%
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile
 }


\begin{document}

\section{Data Overview}
\begin{datasnippets}
% Formaat: naam (dit wordt in het document gebruikt om het commando te gebruiken), korte beschrijving (KORT!), lange beschrijving (duidelijk!), waarde (enkel de waarde, liefst in \code{} wrap)
\datasnippet{someVariable}{Variable}{Just an example}{ThisWorks}
\datasnippet{aProblem}{Problem Variable}{An illustration of a value that layouts fine, but is exported incorrectly.}{A_B01}
\end{datasnippets}

\section{Data Usage}

As you can see, I can now simply refer to \someVariableValue\ and its full description: \someVariableFull . A side effect is that upon compiling, a properties file is generated which can be used during testing.

\end{document}
```

EDIT2: To allow `%` in the arguments of `\datasnippet` we can change the catcode of `%` in the environment `datasnippets`. This way `%` is treated as a normal character, this way, comments are not supported inside of the environment. The only thing, which doesn't work this way, is to have a `\` as the last character in the arguments of `\datasnippet`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\date{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}}
\newwrite\tempfile


\edef\althashchar{\string#\space}%
\newcounter{datasnippets}
\newcommand{\datasnippet}[4]{%
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\unexpanded{#1=#4}}
  \refstepcounter{datasnippets}\label{data:#1}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1lc\endcsname{\MakeLowercase{#2}}%    
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Description\endcsname{#3}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Value\endcsname{\code{#4}}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #1Full\endcsname{#3 (waarde: \code{#4})}%
  \thedatasnippets. & #2 & \code{#4} & #3 \\
    \addlinespace
}
\newenvironment{datasnippets}
 {
     \catcode`\%=11
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=scenarios.properties
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\althashchar This is a generated file, *DO NOT EDIT* directly.}
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\althashchar Instead, update the data snippets inside the data.tex file of the scenarios documentation and regenerate.}

    \par
        \small
        \begin{longtable}{
            p{0.4cm}
            p{4cm}
            p{3cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-0.4cm-4cm-3cm\relax}
        }
        \toprule
        & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Description} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
 }
 {%
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile
 }


\begin{document}

\section{Data Overview}
% Formaat: naam (dit wordt in het document gebruikt om het commando te gebruiken), korte beschrijving (KORT!), lange beschrijving (duidelijk!), waarde (enkel de waarde, liefst in \code{} wrap)
\begin{datasnippets}
\datasnippet{someVariable}{Variable}{Just an example}{ThisWorks}
\datasnippet{aProblem}{Problem Variable}{An illustration of a value that layouts
fine, but is exported incorrectly.}{A_B01%\ }
\end{datasnippets}
% comment

\section{Data Usage}

As you can see, I can now simply refer to \someVariableValue\ and its full description: \someVariableFull . A side effect is that upon compiling, a properties file is generated which can be used during testing.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @YvesV. note that this way `%` is impossible to enter into your last field.

Comment: I do not have such a variable right now, but I am interested to see how the approach could be adapted to allow any kind of character.

Comment: @YvesV. you could (temporarily) change the catcode of `%` to allow it.